# How can I destructure tuples into typed variables?

Tags: types, rust, tuples, pattern-matching

I'm trying to decompose a tuple into variables, and then cause an error by having one of the types mentioned incorrectly:

```
fn main() {
    let tup = (500, 6.4, 1);
    let (x: bool, y: f32, z: i16) = tup;
    println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, z);
}
```

My idea was that the compiler would raise an error because `x` is given as `bool` but is being matched to `500`. Surprisingly, it's the last statement where the compiler complains, saying that x, y, and z were not found in this scope:

I tried it another way:

```
fn main() {
    let tup = (500, 6.4, 1);
    let mut x: bool = true;
    let mut y: f32 = true;
    let mut z: i16 = true;
    (x, y, z) = tup;
    println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, z);
}
```

This time, the compiler does raise the expected error, but it also says that the left-hand side of `(x, y, z) = tup;` isn't valid. Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: Regarding "Surprisingly, it's the last statement where the compiler complains": that's not my experience (from trying with http://play.rust-lang.org . There are multiple errors, and the first one is about the line before it.

Comment: For the last one, you would need to use `let`.

Comment: But what is your goal, if you're trying to assign `500` to a `bool`? Do you want to produce errors, or are you looking for some form of an implicit cast?

Comment: @Evert Please see https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7091e8a4c0f71f420048d1b3891990bc&version=stable. `(x, y, z) = tup;` is the only line that the compiler complains about.

Comment: @Evert Trying to produce errors. :)

Comment: In your playground example, use `let` in the tuple destructring, and see what you get. Probably only warnings.

Comment: Trying to produce errors (and getting them) is easy. I guess you want to understand your errors, but the question behind that is: why? Do you want to try and understand how the compiler works, how it parses the code? Or are you just looking for a convenient way to destructure tuples, as per your title.

Comment: @Evert If I add `let`, the compiler that the `mut` are unnecessary. And If I remove the `mut` as well, it says x, y, and z are unused variables. I think when saying `let (x, y, z)`, new bindings are created.

Comment: Well, yes, of course new bindings are created. That's how it works.

Comment: @Evert I'm actually writing a tutorial as I learn Rust myself, and want to show how the compiler complains if we mess up types.

Comment: That makes more sense, but without that context, the question is unclear.

Comment: @Evert I've added that to the question, thank you. So how can I show type error and destructuring at the same time?

Comment: Note that for the actual code, I assume you're thinking of having existing variables (with certain values), and then want to reassign those variables to the tuple values. `let (x, y, z) = ...` will do that, or `let (mut x, mut y, mut z) = ...`.

Comment: Well, I don't mind if the type can be specified while destructuring itself. I attempted that in my first code snippet but failed. As for the other example, do you mind writing an answer with full code? :)

Comment: Possibly, you can't (show the two errors at the same time): Rust allows you to do `let x: bool = true; <...>; let x: i16 = 4;`. Since tuple unpacking requires the `let` statement (except in a match), you're just reassigning the same name to a new variable (with a different type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the errors more carefully; the first case's very first one was:

```
error: expected one of `)`, `,`, or `@`, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:3:11
  |
3 |     let (x: bool, y: f32, z: i16) = tup;
  |           ^ expected one of `)`, `,`, or `@` here
```

Which indicates that you can't provide types next to the variable names when you pattern match against a tuple. This is a parsing error which rendered that whole line invalid and caused `x`, `y` and `z` not to be found for the purposes of `println!()`:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `x` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:28
  |
4 |     println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, z);
  |                            ^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `y` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:31
  |
4 |     println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, z);
  |                               ^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `z` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:4:34
  |
4 |     println!("{}, {}, {}", x, y, z);
  |                                  ^ not found in this scope
```

As for the second case, there's a bunch of invalid assignments; `y` and `z` are numbers, but you try to assign `bool`s to them; `(x, y, z) = ...` is also an invalid assignment - it doesn't pattern  match (in Rustc versions < 1.59.0) unless it's within a `let` binding.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation! So, it seems I can't use tuple destructuring without using `let`, which means without shadowing existing variables?

Comment: Not necessarily; you can also perform assignment with literals (e.g. `let (a, b, c) = (1, 2.0, true);`) or by introducing new variables, e.g. `let (d, e, f) = (a, b, c);`.

Comment: ljedrz (somehow SO won't let me tag you) - I was asking whether I can use existing variables without shadowing them.

Comment: @dotslash it's a comment under my answer, so I don't need tagging; `let (d, e, f) = (a, b, c);` doesn't shadow `a`, `b` or `c` and if they implement `Copy` they aren't even moved (they still can be used afterwards).

Comment: Umm, actually I wanted `(a, b, c)` to be on the left side, and also have `a`, `b`, and `c` declared beforehand. Not possible, I suppose . . . ?

Comment: @dotslash no, that is not possible.

Answer (score 24):

When doing tuple assignment, you should first specify all your variables, then all the types:

```
let (x, y, z): (bool, f32, i16) = tup;
```

gives the error you expect ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4a3e617a04494834f788dcf075f23903&version=stable))

Comment: I thought this would lead me to an answer to "convert into" this type by default (like you can with `.collect()`) and wanted to try out if it would work but nope! I'm going to just cast them `as` for now :) Cheers though, very useful to know this is indeed possible even if just for correctness!