# Is it possible to destructure a tuple with an irrefutable pattern in a function declaration?

Tags: rust, tuples, pattern-matching, destructuring

In rust I can currently do,

```
// this function accepts k,v
fn foo(
    k: &str, v: u8
) -> bool {
    true
}
```

But I can not destructure the arguments in the signature,

```
// this function accepts (k,v) tuple
fn bar(
    (k: &str, v: u8) // notice the parens
) -> bool {
    true
}
```

Is it possible to destructure a tuple with an irrefutable pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destructuring tuples into typed variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667195/destructuring-tuples-into-typed-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have to do is type the whole tuple not the components inside it,

```
// this function accepts (k,v) tuple
fn baz(
    (k, v): (&str, u8) // notice the parens
) -> bool {
    true
}
```